# Using insertAdjacentHTML gives error in.js file but not in console snippet

Tags: javascript

It works in CodePen and in console log snippet: https://codepen.io/MistaPrime/pen/ZEYLvaR

But when inserting it inside of a .js file it gives this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null`

The objective of the code is to insert a copy of `#numeric-toc` contents after `.rounded-block` and create a new div called `#sticky-numeric-toc` which will hold the copy of `#numeric-toc` contents.

```
// insert sticky menu holder into the sidebar
var stickyMenu = document.querySelector('.rounded-block');
stickyMenu.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="sticky-numeric-toc">two</div>');

// copy-paste table of contents into sticky sidebar
document.getElementById("sticky-numeric-toc").innerHTML =
document.getElementById("numeric-toc").innerHTML;


// on scroll add fixed class to sidebar
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var elementTarget = document.getElementById('numeric-toc');
  if (window.scrollY > (elementTarget.offsetTop + elementTarget.offsetHeight)) {
      document.querySelector('#sticky-numeric-toc').classList.add('anotherclass');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#sticky-numeric-toc').classList.remove('anotherclass');
  }
});
```

```
<div id="numeric-toc">
THIS WILL BE CONTENT TO COPY
</div>



<div class="rounded-block">     
</div>
```

Basically my issue is that I cannot make this code work in the browser using a stickysidebar.js which is loaded after the contents. It works on CodePen and snippet but not once the site is launched.

Should I use something other than `insertAdjacentHTML` ?

Comment: Just wondering - do you assert stickyMenue or .rounded-block exists - your error points to something like this. Typo maybe?

Comment: The element in the sidebar will be sticky, the element `#sticky-numeric-toc` will be sticky once inserted.

Comment: Ye I understand - what I mean is querySelector returns element or null - if null it means .rounded-block is not existent thus typo or something.

Comment: @MistaPrime most likely your JS isn't loaded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine as long as I add `window.onload` around it:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // your code ...
}
```

Gives same result as the codepen example for me. Maybe codepen does this by default before running JS?

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution, it has worked like a charm. You are probably right that CodePen does that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The issue looks to be how the file is being loaded. I tested your code with the following methods and did not receive an error. However, if I had the script tag at the top of the page I did encounter your issue.

It sounds like your javascript is being loaded before the DOM has had time to load so `var stickyMenu = document.querySelector('.rounded-block');` will return null because it doesn't exist yet.

You could do a couple of things to solve this. Moving your javascript to the end of the file will allow the page to load before running the javascript.

You could also use jquery's `$('document').ready(function(){});` where it will wait for the DOM to be "ready" before executing the code in the call back.

The pure JS version of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t) but it's not as neat as the other 2 examples

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense and I learned a lot. I attributed the other answer the bounty as it was pure JS and the code was ready to go. Much appreciation for your input and time, I am very grateful.